How to change assigned program id in solana network
I have the issue.
I don't know about the how to change the assigned program id.
Please help me.
I don't know well abut the solana contract.
First, I have to deploy the solana contract.
If you know about this, I want to discuss about it.
I'm looking forward to your reply.
Thank you.

I'm finding the Jon C.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To change the program ID of your smart contract.

Generate a new Keypair that will be the new program ID authority

solana-keygen new -o ./target/deploy/<PROGRAM_NAME>.json --force --no-bip39-passphrase


Get the corresponding pubkey

solana-keygen pubkey ./target/deploy/<PROGRAM_NAME>.json


Replace the old program ID with the new one in Anchor.toml and lib.rs files. You can search and replace.


If you don't mind, could you let me know about the your contact info?
I want to discuss about the my solana project.
What do you think?
Thank you
